# How do I throw an exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an if statement, and I want it so that if the condition is true, an error is thrown. It's a form for users to remove items from an array called myArr, and if that item does not exist in myArr I want it to throw an error.

```
$('#remove_user').submit(function(){
    id = $('#user_num').val();
    diffVal = $.grep(myArr, function(value, i){
        return value != id;
    });
    if (diffVal.length == myArr.length) {
        //I want the error here to say "Does not exist."
    } else {
        myArr = diffVal
    };
    $('#user_list').html('');
    for (var i=0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) {
        $('#user_list').append('<li>' +myArr[i]+ '</li>');
    };
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have a look here, about halfway down the page: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter5.html

Comment: It should be mentioned that throwing errors in JavaScript is rarely a good idea.

Comment: You could use jQuery's `$.error` method to do this, then any plugins that override the `$.error` method will receive this error. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.error/ `$.error("Does not exist.");` Really only useful if you override the default method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`throw "Item does not exist!"`

But I've found that it's better to throw an `Error` object, like so:

`throw new Error("Item does not exist!");`

If you throw an `Error` you get marginally better tracibility. Error handling in JavaScript is sadly still abysmal.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly would this do? Would it put red text above the textbox saying "Item does not exist"?

Comment: no, it interupts execution of your javascript code. To display the error to the user you must catch it (with a `try { ... } catch (e) { ... }`). This works similar to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *[throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)*:

```
if (diffVal.length == myArr.length) {
    //I want the error here to say "Does not exist."
    throw "Item does not exist in the array";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is to also use trace when throwing an error

```
if (diffVal.length == myArr.length) {
    //I want the error here to say "Does not exist."
    Console.log("Error: Does not exist");
    Console.trace();
    throw new Error("Item does not exist");
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if the trace was in the `Error` though so you can catch it somewhere and make nice error report :) Ah, one can dream ..

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - That sounds interesting. :)

Comment: It does, right! Have you ever tried wrestling a trace from a caught `Error`? It's madness I tell you m̒ͪͤ͛a͍̥̗͎̒d̝̳̱͙͇ṉe̝̟͇͚͇ͪ͆͌s̋͒ͮs̟̘̫̞̹̾ͤ!